# .NET threading API resources

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can anyone recommend any resources on the .NET threading API?  I've used a few of the basic features, but I'd like to get more familiar with the more obscure parts.

Comment: Do you mean delegates, ThreadPool, creating you own threads? What parts do you call basic and what obscure?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) is a pretty decent resource...

Comment: You can't beat Albahari's book. Start with his examples and build yourself some prototypes - no better way to learn!

Answer (score 1):

The guide found [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/index.shtml) has been extremely helpful to myself and many others... is this the sort of information you're looking for?

Also, [MSDN's overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx) of the `System.Threading` namespace is about as comprehensive as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

[Concurrent Programming on Windows by Joe Duffy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) -- everything you will ever need to know and more.